# D3. How do I use a function to set more then one attribute using the .attr method

Tags: d3.js, svg

In `D3` I now set the coordinates of a rect thusly:

```
.attr({
        x:function(d) { return histogram.renderX(d); },
        width:function(d) { return histogram.renderWidth(d); },

        y:function(d) { return histogram.renderY(d); },
        height:function(d, i) { return histogram.renderHeight(d, i); } 
}
```

This does not give me the flexibility I am after to configure the rect. I prefer to do something along the lines of:

```
.attr(coordinates(d, t));
```

where `coordinates` looks like this:

```
    function coordinates(datum, index) {

        var coords = {};

        coords[      'x' ] = function(datum) { return histogram.renderX(datum); };
        coords[  'width' ] = function(datum) { return histogram.renderWidth(datum); };

        coords[      'y' ] = function(datum) { return histogram.renderY(datum); };
        coords[ 'height' ] = function(datum) { return histogram.renderHeight(datum, index); };

        return coords;
    }
```

The function I envision will do something more interesting to set `x,y,width,height`. I am unclear on the proper syntax to use here. Can someone please clarify for me?

Comment: [each](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#each)?  `.each(function(d){ var x = myAwesomeFunction(d); var self = d3.select(this); self.attr('someAttr', x.SomeValue); self.attr('someAttr2', x.SomeValue2); }`

Comment: Ah hah. Yep. Thx. Pose as a question so I can give you props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.each](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#each) for this:

```
...
.each(function(d){ 
  var x = myAwesomeFunction(d); 
  var self = d3.select(this); 
  self.attr('someAttr', x.SomeValue); 
  self.attr('someAttr2', x.SomeValue2); 
});
```